# how to add new custom field taxonomy in woocomerce?

Tags: wordpress, field, woocommerce, meta

I'm struggling to create a new custom field taxonomy in woocommerce, for the product page, I've been looking information how to do this but I can not find anything . ..  If anybody can help me, will be amazing !! I'd like so after that, to make it display in the page of course.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/pelmered/WooCommerce-Custom-Product-Taxonomy

Just drop this into your plugins folder, edit the $taxonomies variable(taxonomy names) in woocommerce-custom-taxonomy.php and then activate the plugin. It could not be any simpler to add custom taxonomies to your WooCommerce products!

This link help you.

Answer (score 0):

with this plugin you can create a custom fields at your custom post types, its really simple download the plugin, install, at your dashoboard you can see "custom fields" menu and configure your custom field in your template file:

```
<?php the_field('fieldId'); ?>
```

the plugin link is
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/

Comment: thank you, ive been trying to use this plugin but i dt manage to make it work . . .

Should i put the code in functions.php, then to import all the value for each product of this field, import them via the csv file with for example: "tax:product_myid" and the code will be: 

<?php the_field('tax:product_myid'); ?>

and the name of the field via the plugin: tax:product_myid

Isnt it ?

Comment: http://wp-types.com/documentation/user-guides/how-to-import-content-into-wordpress-using-csv/

Comment: where should i put the code 

<?php the_field('fieldId'); ?>

Please ? If i put it in functions.php i have a syntax error . . . shoudl I add a functions ?? thank you for your time

Comment: in your functions need the post info, the code <?php the_field(''); ?> in your single

Comment: allright, and which is the post info to put in the functions ? Right now I have the field in my product admin to add it, but it doesn display in front end . . . thank you for our help =)